# What do I call a person who is participating in a survey?

Tags: terminology

I am writing about a survey I wrote to evaluate the usability of a program. When describing the methodology of the survey, I refer to the person conducting the survey as the investigator. What should I call the other person?

> The investigator gave the [?] a tour of the functions of the application.

Comment: Given the usual case of a survey being completely for the benefit of the commissioner; "victim" comes to mind.

Comment: Since I gave them chocolate, are they 'bribees'?

Comment: I'd also just say that *survey* is probably inappropriate for this specific example, which looks more like a UAT (User Acceptance Testing) process.  In which case the **[?]** should probably be called *testers*, *users*, or maybe even *clients*.

Comment: You would call that person a *retiree*.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I suspect *participant* may be more common, particularly when pluralised, but that may simply be because it's a more common word applicable in many other contexts. For a single individual in this context, ***respondent*** seems more precise to me.

It's less common, but I think *interviewee* is equally suitable in OP's context.

Comment: Participant just indicates involvement. The investigator is also a participant.  A respondant indicates not only involvement, but a role or primary activities or responsibilities.

Comment: @JustinC: Totally agree. Belatedly I've "emboldened" ***respondent*** to make it crystal clear that it's better than *participant* for OP's context.

Answer (score 13):

You would call that person a *participant* in the survey.

Answer (score 10):

I have some experience in the surveying industry and we call them respondents.

Comment: As I suspected. I just googled "+survey +participant" and got 17M hits. Significantly less for "+survey +respondent", but the first query got lots of results from blogs, newspapers, advertisers, etc., whereas the second seems to have more results from pollsters and others in the business.

Answer (score 4):

For completeness: Google gives some hits for *surveyee*, e.g. on [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/surveyee).

But I do think *participant* or *respondent* as suggested in other answers goes better with *investigator*.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the answers have decided on *participant*, which I think is the most appropriate.  We can also use ***respondent***, according to the following combase.ca [glossary](http://www.combase.ca/resources/glossary) entry:

> Respondent: Refers to the selected
>   person in the household who will
>   answer the questionnaire.

Answer (score 1):

Someone who participates of anything is a *participant*. Someone who is using an application is a *user*. Someone being investigated is a *suspect*. Someone being surveyed can also be a *respondent*.

But in the instance, I would just say:

> The survey **person** conducted the **participant** through an application's function tour.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *participant*, omitting *in the survey* if the context allows...

> The investigator gave the participant a tour
>   of the functions of the application.

Answer (score 0):

It used to be a survey assistant who held the pole but with the advent of robotic total stations a lot of it is now a one-man job so the surveyor does everything.

Comment: You have misunderstood, I am talking about the other person.

Comment: @fredley, yes you used to have another person to do the unskilled pole holding part. While you worked the instrument but now the instruments are remote controlled so you can hold the pole - saving a salary

Comment: Instruments? Pole holding? I have no idea what you're talking about. As stated in my survey this is a usability survey for an app I wrote.

Comment: mgb is apparently talking about a land survey. I fail to see the relevance.

Answer (score 0):

Other popular terms for a person who fills out a survey:

individual, person, member of that demographic group, member of the population, respondent, writer, ...

If you choose a certain category of people to take your survey (rather than a randomly selected people in your city), then you might use terms that apply to that category:
computer user, Mac user, iPhone user, Android user, guitarist, grandmother, etc.