# Questionee? Inquiree? Interrogatee?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do you call somebody who asks a question and somebody who answers a question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12999/what-do-you-call-somebody-who-asks-a-question-and-somebody-who-answers-a-questio)
>   [What do I call a person who is participating in a survey?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18022/what-do-i-call-a-person-who-is-participating-in-a-survey)

What's a proper but simple one-word description of a person to whom a question is being asked?

Comment: hmmm, perhaps not

Answer (score 10):

***Addressee*** is the usual technical term for anyone being talked to, without regard to whether the talking involves a question, a statement, an order, a promise, or whatever. I don't know of any that specifically refer to questions, though.

*Questionee* and *interrogatee* are grotesque hapax legomena that call attention to themselves, and to the pomposity of their user. Use the person's name instead, if you know it, or find a more comfortable term to refer to them with.

Comment: +1 for using the phrase "grotesque hapax legomena," which calls attention to itself...

Comment: _Questionee_ appears (now at least) to be a grotesque ex-_hapax legomena_.

Answer (score 5):

Merriam-Webster has *[questionee](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/questionee)*:

> one that is questioned

and [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/interrogatee) and [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/interrogatee) have *interrogatee*.

Though these are uncommon words, I believe their meanings are clear enough for them to be useful in apt circumstances.

I'd prefer a word like *respondent*, though, if the questionee actually responds.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel.  Respondent is useful, but I'm trying to properly identify people in a database I'm developing. I think 'questionee' will work fine for my purposes. I checked Dictionary.com and it wasn't in there, but since one respected source lists it, that's fine with me. I couldn't add it as a tag 'cause I'm a newbie to this site, but feel free to add it if you want - ya never know when someone else might make use of it!

Comment: Please be careful with your sources: Dictionary.com uses Merriam-Webster, and Wiktionary is not a separate dictionary, since its definitions often come from the Merriam-Webster Dictionary (verbatim, in this case)! I'm happy you gave links, though, and your answer is good.

Comment: @Translator1983 Thanks for the remarks - I think that the words stand well on their own merits (being common words with a common ending), so I wasn't super picky about the dictionaries.  But you're right about being careful.