# What single, unambiguous word(s) could I use to distinguish a user-instance of a survey from the reference to the survey itself?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

For reference, I have first checked other questions/answers including: [Questionee? Inquiree? Interrogatee?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73616/questionee-inquiree-interrogatee?noredirect=1&lq=1) (and it's listed "possible duplicates") but those are in reference to the user rather than the survey associated to the user.

Breaking it down, a survey by itself is just a template used for retrieving individual responses. Once the survey has been copied and served individually, it has become an instance of that survey. "Response" and "instance" are too ambiguous for referring to an individual survey specifically. "Surveyee", "inquiree", "interrogatee" and "questionee" are more specific but they refer to the person/user/subject who started/completed any number of surveys and not their unique set of answers for one in particular. If I have a pile of unassigned surveys and a pile of assigned surveys, I would refer to a random selection from each pile as "a survey" and "this person's survey" respectfully. It is the latter I wish to identify as a single, unambiguous noun.

All I have been satisfied using thus far in my (web) project is 'survey-instance' (hyphenated for URL compatibility) but I cannot shake the thought there is a better, single-word descriptor.

Comment: If you consider that your "pile of assigned surveys" is a *sampling frame*, your single instance would be a **sample** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_frame https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(statistics)

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest:

> **[Submission](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/submission)**
>
> : a document that you formally give to someone who will make a decision about it

Each person fills out and *submits* a survey to you; you have a pile of *submissions*.

Answer (score 0):

**reply** and **respondent.**

reply:

> 1
>   :  something said, written, or done in answer or response

"Reply." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 2 May 2017.

respondent:

> 1c :  a person who responds to a poll

"Respondent." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 2 May 2017.