# What is the recipient of a question called?

Tags: questions

When I ask you a question I am the inquisitor or or the inquirer. But what are you, the one to whom I'm asking the question?
Here's the example I'm working with: the children's book "Are you My Mother?"...the hatchling asks that question to many things (animals, objects); I'd love to have one word to describe those animals and things he's posing the question to...the object of the inquirer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I can't find a definition for "inquiree".

Comment: Possible duplicate of three other questions:  (1)http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12999/what-do-you-call-somebody-who-asks-a-question-and-somebody-who-answers-a-question:     (2) http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18022/what-do-i-call-a-person-who-is-participating-in-a-survey   (3) http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18022/what-do-i-call-a-person-who-is-participating-in-a-survey  Please check all three; if none of them answer your question, then edit your question to explain why none of them do.

Comment: @StevieV It was a candidate word used by the OP in their question. Hence the query.

Comment: I don't think any of the answers in the maybe-duplicate questions fit the OP's example, so I have voted to reopen.

Comment: @ab2 Can you explain why Merriam-Webster's  '**questionee**:

one that is questioned' doesn't answer 'But what are you, the one to whom I'm asking [sic] the question?'?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth  Technically it would, but (a) I have an allergy to -ee words and (b) it sounds odd in the context of the OPs example, which adds up to: a feeling there must be something better.

Comment: @ab2 But there was a valid answer. Your not liking does not constitute a reason to re-open this duplicate (I don't like that answer ['addressee'] either – but I accept it's an answer, and that there are acceptable 'answers' there (J Lawler's gets my vote) and probably the best that exists).Your correct course of action is to close-vote here and concentrate on the original.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth  OK.

Comment: The answer of "questionee" is not good; it is not a commonly known word; thank you for re-opening because none of the three other questions  previously asked fit my exact question.

Comment: 'Questionee' is _not_ a wonderful answer. But, as I say, it's quite possibly the best single-word answer available. Most people would use 'the person asked' / 'the people asked'.

Answer (score 0):

This person is called the:

**Respondent**

See the definition at [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/respondent)

Comment: What if a person is asked but doesn't  reply? I don't think *respondent* works in that case?

Comment: @k1eran definitely a very good point. Then in that case they definitely wouldn't be responding to anything would they?

Comment: I nearly answered **target** but seems a bit imprecise?

Comment: @k1eran No I think that definitely works, only target can be applied to anything. However target (person the question is directed at) might work better because the person being asked doesn't necessarily have to respond. In context "the target of the question" makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: Correct about "what if the person doesn't reply"; thus respondent doesn't work; and "target of the question" doesn't work in that it needs to be one word if possible. Here's the example I'm working with: the children's book "Are you My Mother?"...the hatchling asks that question to many things (animals, objects); I'd love to have one word to describe those animals and things he's posing the question to.

Comment: @BarryShafer did the answers to any of ab2 's list of questions help you? If not then you need to show you've read through them and that they don't work in OP.

Comment: As John Lawler says [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/73625/17956) it’s ***Adressee*** which works regardless of whether they answer or not.

Comment: @Jim Thank you for sharing, one can be addressed about anything. Whether or not it is a question. I like Daniel's answer on that same page you just linked.

Comment: I think *adressee* is unambigious in the proper context and that *questionee* sounds so fabricated that if that were the only word available I’d rephrase to avoid it.

Comment: @Jim addressee is ambiguous in this context, by definition.

Comment: In that case, so is *respondent*

Comment: @Jim yes I agree.

Comment: @StevieV; Yes, I did read the other questions and they only helped in confirming to me that there may not be a good, single word that describes the receiver of a conversational question.

Comment: @Bshafe5 it actually sounds like "questionee" may be your best bet. See the link that Jim provided (seven comments up from here).

Comment: Thanks all! As much as I might hate to go with an "-ee" I think you're right about it being the best bet. It's interesting that there is not a fitting word for this context. Nevertheless, this question has introduced me to this great community. Thank you!

Comment: @Bshafe5 Glad to help, glad you've had a good experience here.